# Error in the placeholder in a binder

Tags: c++

```
void f(int i,const string& s){cout << i << s;}

auto g = bind(f,2,_1);
```

I get an error, _1 was not declared in this scope

Comment: are you using the std::placeholders namespace?

Comment: At the same time, if you're using C++11 or greater, you might as well just start learning to write lambdas. They end up being much less confusing in general, IMO.

Comment: This is a good example why its good to type out the namespaces and not use Using-declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto g = std::bind(f, 2, _1);
```

Better:

```
auto h = std::bind(f, 2, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Best:

```
auto i = [](auto&& x) { f(2, x); };
```

For extra bonus points:

```
auto j = [](auto&& x) {
    using type = std::decay_t<decltype(x)>;
    f(2, std::forward<type>(x));
};
```

Comment: I tried but it appears there is an error in your lambdas, parameter declared auto. Is it C++14 feature?

Comment: @MiloLu sorry, yes. that's c++14. For c++11 you must specify the type in which case it will be auto i = [](const string& x) { f(2, x); };