# How to fix "error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope"?

Tags: c++, c++11, binding, stl

I'm currently trying to bind a function to an algorithm I'm intending to use.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> coll{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    vector<int>::iterator pos;
    pos = find_if (coll.begin(), coll.end(), 
                    bind(greater<int>(),_1,3)); 

    return 0;
}
```

and get this error feedback:

```
AlgoTesting.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
AlgoTesting.cpp:184:41: error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope
                     bind(greater<int>(),_1,3)); // criterion
                                         ^~
AlgoTesting.cpp:184:41: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from algostuff.hpp:15:0,
                 from AlgoTesting.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:275:34: note:   ‘std::placeholders::_1’
     extern const _Placeholder<1> _1;
                                  ^~
```

I'm struggling to understand what the error log means. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Using a lambda rather than `std::bind` is often easier, gives better error messages and as a bonus might even produce faster code

Comment: @AlanBirtles: thanks, no doubt of it. Please also find my comment to the answer below. I faced the problem due of the usage of `bind` itself, that why I write this post. It is really not about which one is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include [`<functional>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) and use [`std::placeholders::_1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders)

```
pos = find_if (coll.begin(), coll.end(), bind(greater<int>(),placeholders::_1,3));
```

An easier option is to use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
pos = find_if(coll.begin(), coll.end(), [](int v) { return std::greater<int>{}(v, 3); });
```

or

```
pos = find_if(coll.begin(), coll.end(), [](int v) { return 3 < v; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of using `lambda`. It is indeed lot easier, but I'm currently learning the usage of `bind` and my problem appeared specifically on that use case.

Comment: @dboy Ok. I find it best to mention lambdas whenever `bind` pops up.

Answer (score 3):

To use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the header [`#include <functional>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) needs to be included and also don't forget to `using namespace placeholders`.

some additional information is also provided in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410532/error-in-the-placeholder-in-a-binder)